# Error!!! cant concatenate the tuple to non float

Tags: python

```
stack = []
  closed = []
  currNode = problem.getStartState()
  stack.append(currNode)
  while (len(stack) != 0):
     node = stack.pop()
     if problem.isGoalState(node):
        print "true"
        closed.append(node)
     else:
         child = problem.getSuccessors(node)
         if not child == 0:
            stack.append(child)
         closed.apped(node)
   return None
```

code of successor is:

```
def getSuccessors(self, state):
    """
    Returns successor states, the actions they require, and a cost of 1.

     As noted in search.py:
         For a given state, this should return a list of triples, 
     (successor, action, stepCost), where 'successor' is a 
     successor to the current state, 'action' is the action
     required to get there, and 'stepCost' is the incremental 
     cost of expanding to that successor
    """

    successors = []
    for action in [Directions.NORTH, Directions.SOUTH, Directions.EAST, Directions.WEST]:
      x,y = state
      dx, dy = Actions.directionToVector(action)
      nextx, nexty = int(x + dx), int(y + dy)
      if not self.walls[nextx][nexty]:
        nextState = (nextx, nexty)
        cost = self.costFn(nextState)
        successors.append( ( nextState, action, cost) )

    # Bookkeeping for display purposes
    self._expanded += 1 
    if state not in self._visited:
      self._visited[state] = True
      self._visitedlist.append(state)

    return successors
```

The error is:

```
File line 87, in depthFirstSearch
    child = problem.getSuccessors(node)
  File  line 181, in getSuccessors
    nextx, nexty = int(x + dx), int(y + dy)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple
```

When we run the following commands:

```
 print "Start:", problem.getStartState()
  print "Is the start a goal?", problem.isGoalState(problem.getStartState())
  print "Start's successors:", problem.getSuccessors(problem.getStartState())
```

we get:

```
Start: (5, 5)
Is the start a goal? False
Start's successors: [((5, 4), 'South', 1), ((4, 5), 'West', 1)]
```

Comment: this is not the same question. I dont have free time to ask repeated questions here. The error is different but the code is same. I have also put more details into it.

Comment: now plz dont close this question also

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple` == `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple`. Same question.

Comment: But i dint get teh answer and they closed my question. so i need to ask it for 1 more time

Comment: instead of wasting time on this issue , can u plz help me.I really want to make it work.

Comment: Instead of wasting our time, take a look at the original response, take a look at the FAQ, and try to figure out why your question was originally closed. It's not because we're jealous of your extreme programming skills, I guarantee it.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
nextx, nexty = int(x + dx), int(y + dy)
```

to this:

```
print x, y, dx, dy, state
nextx, nexty = int(x + dx), int(y + dy)
```

I guarantee you will see () around something besides state. That means your value is a tuple:

`int(x + dx), int(y + dy)`

You cannot concatenate a float and a tuple and convert the result to integer, it just won't work:

```
In [57]: (5, 5) + 3.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

c:\<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple
```

Comment: Yes...u r awesome....I am getting the same result.


        5 5 0.0 -1.0 (5, 5)


      5 5 -1.0 0.0 (5, 5)


But I cant change the code in getSuccessor function. I'm not allowed to do that. Only I can do is to change my code written at the top of teh question. So what should I do now?

Comment: That makes no sense. `state` is a tuple, but you're getting an error from this operation: `nextx, nexty = int(5 + 0.0), int(5 - 1.0)` and that plainly doesn't generate an error. In the directory where you have these(this?) file do you have any `.pyc` files?

Comment: The file in which the " successor func"  is defined, has a .pyc file also but I dint look through it. What should I use from that file??

Comment: I think, instead of making a state a "tuple"..can I use it as matrix that can store the values.

Comment: delete the `.pyc` files only and see if that helps, because there's no way that code should be giving you an error, but if something was changed in the file and it was `import`ed, then it's possible that the `.pyc` file hasn't been updated.

Comment: should I delete all the .pyc filese or just that specific file?

Comment: I deleted all the .pyc files from the direc that are realted to the project
But it is still showing the same error.

Comment: for x, y, dx, and dy, do `print x, type(x)` - do any of them show tuple?

Comment: Should i put this line of code before Nextx and nexty in successor fnct

Comment: 5 <type 'int'>


   5 <type 'int'>

This is what I get after putting that line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `x` or `y` (or both) is a tuple when it should be a float/int. I'd make sure that `state` and `node` are what you expect them to be. That's all I can say without knowing more about what `problem.getStartState()` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: problem.getStartState() returns me " (5,5)...this is initial state.
I have given you the results of the functions. See the last lines of my question.

Comment: Ah. Didn't notice it since it wasn't formatted when i first saw the question. Well do what Wayne said to see what x and y really are at that point.

Comment: i did that, he is right. The tuple and float cant be concatenated. And I cant change the code in successor function. The only thing I am allowed to do is to change my own code. what changes in my code and make it work? My code is given at the top of the question.

Answer (score 0):

What this error probably means is that you are trying to concatenate (with +) is a mixture of a float and a tuple, and that isn't defined. Check to see what type of thing `state`, `x`, `y`, `dx`, and `dy` are.

Comment: state is (5,5)- the initial state

dx and dy are the numbers.

Comment: i'd print out state and dx and dy right in the code and double-check that. you're printing values that are not quite directly related to the line that's broken. better to go straight to the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
start_state = problem.getStartState()
    fringe = util.Stack()
    visited = set()
    # Each item in the fringe is a tuple containing the state and a list of actions
    fringe.push((start_state, []))

    while not fringe.isEmpty():
        current_state, actions = fringe.pop()
        if problem.isGoalState(current_state):
            return actions
        visited.add(current_state)
        successors = problem.getSuccessors(current_state)
        for next_state, action, _ in successors:
                   if next_state not in visited:
                    next_actions = actions + [action]
                    fringe.push((next_state, next_actions))
    return []
```

For DFS use this Algorithm.It works best for me in maze search game