# functions in python query

Tags: python

```
def directionToVector(direction, speed = 1.0):
    dx, dy =  Actions._directions[direction]
    return (dx * speed, dy * speed)

def getCostOfActions(self, actions):
    """
    Returns the cost of a particular sequence of actions.  If those actions
    include an illegal move, return 999999.  This is implemented for you.
    """
    if actions == None: return 999999
    x,y= self.startingPosition
    for action in actions:
      dx, dy = Actions.directionToVector(action)
      x, y = int(x + dx), int(y + dy)
      if self.walls[x][y]: return 999999
    return len(actions)

def getCostOfActions(self, actions):
     """
     actions: A list of actions to take

     This method returns the total cost of a particular sequence of actions.
     The sequence must be composed of legal moves
     """

 File "in getCostOfActions
    dx, dy = Actions.directionToVector(action)
  File  in directionToVector
    dx, dy =  Actions._directions[direction]
KeyError: 'N'
```

I am using the last function but the arguments are not accepted by the function. What should be the arguments here? What should their types be?

Comment: Are you trying to call it in the last line of code?

Comment: no...m just usng the last function. The other functions were defined in some other file.I posted all these functions so that U can get the idea of the last func easily

Comment: `getCostOfActions` seems to be defined twice .. ? Also, what do you mean by 'not accepted'? Can you post the line where you're using it, and the error message?

Comment: check the error in edited question

Comment: If you pass in a `string` rather than a list, the first `getCostOfActions` method will iterate over the string, character-by-character. I'd wager (AU$0.50) you passed in 'North'.

Comment: Please format your question correctly. You've stated in a comment below that there are multiple files here. The stack trace is not a part of the source. Also, please do not edit the stack traces before posting them as you may be removing information vital to answering your question.

Comment: Shilpa, this isn't the first time you've asked questions dealing with this same code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249216/error-cant-concatenate-the-tuple-to-non-float I think you *really* need to look at some of the advice in previous comments. I would also suggest that you really learn Python *and* some of the more fundamental programming concepts, because it is obvious by reading your questions that you understand neither, and most of what you're trying to do is way beyond your comprehension!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument, of course is `self`, since this is an *instance method*. This is passed implicitly.

According to the `docstring`, the argument the callers should provide is 'actions: A **list** of actions to take'.

E.g:

```
instance.getCostOfActions([North, East, South, West])
```

N.B: You have two lines thus:

```
def getCostOfActions(self, actions):
def getCostOfActions(self, actions):
```

The first is replaced by the second.

Comment: but i have only 1 direction to pass...oi dont have the list of actions.

Comment: I'm usng this function in the for loop.So for a index- I have 1 direction

Comment: Then, since the function expects a *list* over which to iterate, you shall need to pass your action in a list by enclosing it in square brackets. For example: `instance.getCostOfActions([an_action])`

Comment: i run the 3 rd fuct...2nd is the desciption of 3rd one. it is in other file.

Comment: If these methods are in different files or even different classes, then you should make this abundantly obvious in your question!